# Словообразовательная цепочка

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, приставка

Какая словообразовательная цепочка неверна?

--*земля-> земляной-> землянка

--герой->геройский->геройски*

Мне кажется что первая цепочка.

Answer (score 1):

> Какая словообразовательная цепочка неверна? ...Мне кажется что первая
>   цепочка.

Да в первой-то как раз всё нормально:

**земл**(я) -> земл-**ян**(ой) -> землян-**к**(а)

Что же до второй...

> Ой, неправильно написала вторую цепочку. Теперь исправила.
>
> герой -> геройский -> геройски

Если Вы правильно внесли исправление, то и вторая цепочка верна:

**герой** -> герой-**ск**(ий) -> геройск-**и**

Comment: Ой,неправильно написала вторую цепочку.Теперь исправила.Почему вторая неверна?

Comment: Обе верны, ошибка где-то в других вариантах